# sorting an array based on time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array in the format

```
["09-02-2010", " 05-08-2010", "11-11-2010",  "27-09-2010", "10-12-2010", "09-09-2010", "03-09-2010", "13-08-2010", , "11-10-2010","09-06-2010", "08-06-2010", "07-06-2010" ]
```

I am trying to sort the array based on the decreasing order of dates..

```
     dateArray.sort( mdyOrdD);

     var dateRE = /^(\d{2})[\/\- ](\d{2})[\/\- ](\d{4})/;

      function mdyOrdD(a, b){
       a = a.replace(dateRE,"$3$1$2");
       b = b.replace(dateRE,"$3$1$2");
       if (a>b) return -1;
       if (a <b) return 1;
       return 0; }
```

bt this didnt work our completely.. What could be wrong and is there any other good way to solve this??

Comment: you should convert it into data format and than using < | > would be easy..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your dates are in `DD-MM-YYYY` format and you want them to be `YYYYMMDD` to sort alphabetically, use

```
   a = a.replace(dateRE,"$3$2$1");
   b = b.replace(dateRE,"$3$2$1");
```

instead.

Comment: that was a quick one.. my mistake